# Scala: Typed method that returns object of the provided Type

Tags: scala, constructor, apply, typed

Good day everyone,

I need to create a Typed Class with a Typed function to parse an Array[String] and returns an Array[OutputType]

```
class Data()
class IntData(var element: Int) extends Data
class BoolData(var element: Boolean) extends Data

class ArrayParser[OutputType <: Data]() {
    def parse(in: Array[String]): Array[OutputType] = {
        in.map(s => parseRecord(s))
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
    def parse(in: Array[String]): Array[OutputType] = {
        in.map(s => {
            import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
            if (typeOf[OutputType] =:= typeOf[IntData])
                new IntData(s.toInt)
            else
                new BoolData(s.toBoolean)
        })
    }
```

but I got the error: *Expression of type Array[Data] doesn't conform to expected type Array[OutputType]*

What can I do to achieve the requirements?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not define a Typeclass to parse the string into the relevant type?

```
trait Parser[T <: Data] { 
  def parse(s: String): T
}

implicit val intParser: Parser[IntData] = ???
implicit val boolParser: Parser[BoolData] = ???

def parse[T <: Data : Parser](a: Array[String]): Array[T] = { 
  val p = implicitly[Parser[T]]
  a.map(s => p.parse(s))
}
```

Also I would advise making Data a sealed trait and it's implementations case classes.

Comment: Would add that requiring runtime reflection is generally a symptom there is something wrong before ...

Comment: Thank you Terry. 
Is it correct to create an implicit val like this:
    "implicit val intParser: Parser[IntData] = new IntData(0)"
Is there any way to make parse(s:String) a static member method?

Comment: Thanks. I created a companion object that extends the trait, so I can use "implicit val intParser: Parser[IntData] = IntData"